# Can you parse JSON keys out of a Google Secrets Manager secret?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, secrets

Consider the following *`gcloud`* command where you inject a Google Secrets Manager secret into your *`SERVICE`* Google Cloud Run service—ripped off the [*Use secrets*](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets#mounting-secrets-service) Cloud Run docs page:

```
gcloud run services update SERVICE \
    --set-secrets="ENV_VAR_NAME=SECRET_NAME:VERSION"
```

**Observation:** Notice how you can set your *`ENV_VAR_NAME`* environment variable to the value of the *`SECRET_NAME:VERSION`* secret; but **Question**: Can you parse JSON keys out of a Google Secrets Manager secret?

For example, consider the *`mysecret`* secret set to `{"PASSWORD":"mylastname","TOKEN":"t0k3n"}` like the following shell session illustrates:

```bash
$ gcloud secrets create mysecret --data-file=- <<<'{"PASSWORD":"mylastname","TOKEN":"t0k3n"}'
Created version [1] of the secret [mysecret].
```

Then you parse out that *`PASSWORD`* secret key with the venerable [*jqlang/jq*](https://github.com/jqlang/jq) utility like so:

```bash
$ gcloud secrets versions access 1 --secret=mysecret \
    | jq --raw-output .PASSWORD
mylastname
```

But I think it would be cool to explicitly inject that *`PASSWORD`* secret key into my Cloud Run service, without doing any of JSON parsing outside of gcloud—since then, I can support one-to-many Secrets Manager secret to application secrets ratio.

I'm imagining something like the following:

```
gcloud run services update SERVICE \
    --set-secrets="ENV_VAR_NAME=SECRET_NAME:VERSION:SECRET_KEY"
```

For my earlier example, each of those parameters maps to the following:

1. *`ENV_VAR_NAME`* to `PASSWORD`.
2. *`SECRET_NAME`* to `mysecret`.
3. *`VERSION`* to `1`.
4. ⭐️ *`SECRET_KEY`* to `PASSWORD`. **Note:** This is the area of interest for my question.

Even better would be if there is some default JSON parsing happens.

Can you parse JSON keys out of a Google Secrets Manager secret?

This is what I tried so far:

1. I read the output of the `gcloud run services update --help` command—didn't see anything.
2. I took a cursory look at the https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.secrets.versions/access page—didn't see anything.
3. I smashed the excellent [*BurntSushi/ripgrep*](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) utility into my `~/google-cloud-sdk` directory like `rg set-secrets ~/google-cloud-sdk` to see if I could find any easter eggs hinting at that JSON parsing capability—again I didn't find anything.

**Guess:** Looks like you can't do this sort of JSON parsing thing with that `--set-secrets` gcloud option; but I'm hoping that I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found a previous post with the same concern however they were trying it on AWS. As per [hoangdv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68480980/how-to-extract-fields-from-this-aws-secretsmanager-json-object), they need to set secret as data.SecretString to have it as a normal string. After that, the JSON string must be cast to a JSON object so the information will be accessible by attribute name.
    var secret = `{"username":"***","password":"***","engine":"mysql","host":"***.***.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com","port":3306,"dbname":"***","dbInstanceIdentifier":"***"}<br>`    ;
    const secretObj = JSON.parse(secret);
    console.log(secretObj.host)